# Securely Handling OAuth Tokens and Keys for eLearning Platform Integration with Zoho CRM

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, token, crm, zoho

I am developing an eLearning platform, and I need to integrate it with Zoho CRM to update payment statuses after the payment process. To achieve this, I am using OAuth 2.0 for authentication with Zoho CRM's API.

My integration process involves several steps:

1. Obtaining the Initial Access Token: Without user interaction, after the user authorizes our application, I want to use the authorization code to obtain an initial access token from Zoho CRM.
2. Refreshing Tokens:To ensure that the access token doesn't expire, I need to implement token refreshing using the refresh token provided by Zoho CRM.
3. Revoking Tokens: After my required actions, I want to revoke the access and refresh tokens to enhance security.

I have several questions and concerns:

**1. Token Management for Different Users:**

- How should I manage access tokens for different users on my eLearning platform securely?
- Is it safe to store access and refresh tokens in a database or session variables?

**2. Token Refreshing:**

- How can I implement token refreshing using the refresh token to keep the integration active without manual intervention?

**3. Token Revocation:**

- What is the best practice for revoking access and refresh tokens when a customer completes their interaction?

**4. Securing Authentication Keys:**

- How can I securely store and use client_id and client_secret in my code to prevent exposure?

I would greatly appreciate any insights, best practices, and optimized code examples to help me achieve secure and efficient OAuth integration with Zoho CRM for my eLearning platform. Thank you for your assistance!

This is my existing code for token handling.

```
1$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://accounts.zoho.com/oauth/v2/token',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('client_id' => '','client_secret' => '','redirect_uri' => '','code' => '','grant_type' => 'authorization_code'),
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Cookie: '
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://accounts.zoho.com/oauth/v2/token',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('client_id' => '','client_secret' => '','refresh_token' => '','grant_type' => 'refresh_token'),
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Cookie: '
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;


$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.zohoapis.com/crm/v5/Leads/search?email=test%40gmail.com',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Authorization: Bearer ',
    'Cookie: '
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);

// Check if the response is not empty and is a valid JSON
if (!empty($response)) {
    $data = json_decode($response, true);

    // Check if the JSON was successfully decoded
    if ($data !== null && isset($data['data']) && is_array($data['data'])) {
        // Access and display the last recorded detail
        $recordedDetails = end($data['data']); // Get the last element in the 'data' array
        print_r($recordedDetails);
    } else {
        echo "Invalid or empty 'data' in JSON response.";
    }
} else {
    echo "Empty response received.";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is it safe to store access and refresh tokens in a database or session variables?

It's hard to make this assessment, because ultimately different people have different risk levels for this thing. Plenty of people store this in a database or something like Redis. But you could also store it in some vault designed for storing secrets, which many hosts like Amazon and others have. It *might* be desirable to at least store it in a separate database to reduce the risk of exposure. Security is not binary, it's very much a sliding scale.

> How can I implement token refreshing using the refresh token to keep the integration active without manual intervention?

You keep track of when the tokens expire, and schedule a background task to renew the tokens.

> What is the best practice for revoking access and refresh tokens when a customer completes their interaction?

OAuth2 has a revoke operation for tokens. Not everyone supports it, but they may. This is helpful if your tokens end up on other systems. Ideally your tokens never leave your system, and in this case just deleting the tokens should be just as good.

> How can I securely store and use client_id and client_secret in my code to prevent exposure?

All the usual, Just make sure the tokens never leave your server. Be careful to not emit stack traces when erroring, read the OWASP top 10, etc.